# How to configure a FileCachePath in IISPEED?

Tags: iis-express

I'm having a following error message:
*IISpeed cannot run due to missing configuration. Please check if a valid FileCachePath is configured.(this page is only shown when viewing on the local machine - your visitors will see the normal, but unoptimized website).*

Even thou I have this line: 
`IISpeed FileCachePath c:\iispeed_cache\`
 uncommented in my:
`c:\Program Files\we-amp\release\iispeed.config`

 Please help!

Comment: Are you using it on IIS Express? https://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed/products/iispeed/configuration I don't think it supports IIS Express, but you can ask in its public support forum, https://groups.google.com/a/we-amp.com/forum/#!forum/support

Comment: IISpeed does support IIS express, see https://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed/products/iispeed/installation

Comment: Alex, can you please get in contact with us at info@iispeed.com , we'll figure things out with you and post the answer here for everyone's benefit, are you using it on IIS express?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a FileCachePath in iispeed.conf in the install directory.

```
• For the 64 bits version, open explorer and go to: %ProgramFiles%\we-amp\iispeed\release\
• For the 32 bits version, open explorer and go to:%ProgramFiles(x86)%\we-amp\iispeed\release\
```

On a 64 bits system with a 32 bits application pool you also need to do this in x86 directory.

For example:

pagespeed FileCachePath "c:\pscache\"

Comment: I've tried all you said, still no changes! It just keeps showing this: 
_"IISpeed cannot run due to missing configuration..."_